# Reactjs Routing with history push but doent change the view only the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with a menu and this have a ListGroupItem and try to redirect another component with history push but only change in the url! This url works but it doesn't change the view, I have to press enter to make this work.

I'm new with react, especially with the router, and I'm feeling lost with this. Thanks for any help.

This is my App.js

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Prueba from './Prueba';
import Menu from './header/Menu';

class App extends Component {

  toggle(menu) {
    if (this.state.collapse == menu){
      this.setState({ collapse: false }); 
    }else {
      this.setState({ collapse: menu });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Menu/>
       <Prueba/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my another component with name Prueba.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem,Collapse, Container, CardBody, Card, Row, Col} from 'reactstrap';
import Pais from './UbicacionGeneral/Pais';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Prueba extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = { collapse: false };
    this.routeChange = this.routeChange.bind(this);    
  }

  routeChange() {
    this.props.history.push('Pais');
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){

  }

  toggle(menu) {

    if (this.state.collapse == menu){
      this.setState({ collapse: false }); 
    }else {
      this.setState({ collapse: menu });
    }   
  }

  render() {
    return (
  <BrowserRouter>

    <div className="App text-center">
      <Row>
        <Col  md="2">
          <ListGroup className="List-Principal">
            <ListGroupItem className="List-Principal-Item " onClick={() => this.toggle("ubicacion")} > Ubicacion General </ListGroupItem>

             <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse == "ubicacion"}> 
              <ListGroup>
                <ListGroupItem  onClick={this.routeChange} > Pais </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem  > Estado </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem  > Ciudad </ListGroupItem>
              </ListGroup>
            </Collapse>

          <ListGroupItem  className="List-Principal-Item tex-center" 

          onClick={() => this.toggle("almacen")} > Almacen </ListGroupItem>
                <Collapse  isOpen={this.state.collapse == "almacen"}>
                  <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroupItem  > Crear - Modificar  </ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem  > Verificar Stock   </ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem  > Movimientos  </ListGroupItem>
                  </ListGroup>
                </Collapse>
            </ListGroup>

          </Col>

          <Col  md="10">   
            <Container>
              <Route path="/Pais" component={Pais} />
            </Container>
          </Col>        
        </Row>
      </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Prueba);
```

Finally this is the component I want to see with the history push, named Pais.

Pais.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem,Collapse, Container, CardBody, Card, Row, Col} from 'reactstrap';
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class Pais extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Alert color="primary">
          This is a primary alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
        <Alert color="secondary">
          This is a secondary alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
        <Alert color="success">
          This is a success alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
        <Alert color="danger">
          This is a danger alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
        <Alert color="warning">
          This is a warning alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
        <Alert color="info">
          This is a info alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
        <Alert color="light">
          This is a light alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
        <Alert color="dark">
          This is a dark alert — check it out!
        </Alert>        
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default withRouter (Pais);
```

Comment: try this:     `this.props.history.push('/Pais');`

Comment: Nothing change, same problem! :(

Comment: you could organize your routes in the BrowserRouter in App.js here an example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: Thank you for the advice Nemer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several parts that are incorrect.
First of all, you shouldn't use BrowserRouter in Prueba.js. There should be only one BrowserRouter.
Also, you either put Route inside BrowserRouter or Switch.
As you didn't configure routes properly using BrowserRouter, Switch and Route, url changes but that doesn't reflect to your React App.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I delete BrowserRouter from Prueba.js and history push now works! In you recommendation i have to change the route in that component too?